# Why do I have to buy the same items twice?

Tags: awesomenauts

I've noticed that sometimes when I play *Awesomenauts*, I'll teleport back to the shop to buy items, and everything I've purchased up to that point has to be purchased again.

I'm assuming this is a bug, but I'm really hoping it's intended behavior. As in, I bought Damage +2, played a bit, teleported back, and had to buy Damage +2 again, giving me a total of +4 Damage. However, I worry that this is not the case.

**Why does it make me repurchase items?**

Comment: Some items you can buy more than once, so they provide the same bonus twice.  I think the max you can buy most items is twice, though.  It turns green once you've bought it the max number of times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you can purchase an item multiple times, it is an upgrade and the bonuses are cumulative.  The [Awesomenauts Wiki](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Awesomenauts_Wiki) shows these levels under each [ability's tech trees](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Category:Abilities).  The bonuses it lists are the total bonuses at that level.

[image]

Here, each time Spiked Tongue Piercing is available for purchase in game, it will list +3 Damage.

As mentioned, once you have maxed out a particular upgrade, it will become green in the shop.